# How to bind value to be displayed in html in React?

Tags: html, reactjs, data-binding

I just created my first test in React.
Following an example of a tutorial I have created several buttons that activate a function by which they receive the index of the selected button. The first button selected must show one of the operators of the aray and the next one the opposite, and so on...

```
const operators = ['+', '-'];
const placeHolder = 'o';
function Boxes(props){
    return (
        <AppContext.Consumer>
            {context => {
                const value = context.boxes[props.index];
                const icon = value !== null ? operators[value] : placeHolder;
                const isDone = icon !== placeHolder ? 'done' : '';

                return (
                    <button className="box-active"
                    onClick={() => context.boxAct(props.index)}>
                    {operator}
                    </button>
                )
            }}
        </AppContext.Consumer>
    )
}
```

and here is de function

```
  boxAct = (index) => {
    if (this.state.boxes[index] === null) { 
       this.state.boxes[index] = '+';
    }
  }
```

How can I achieve this? Following the steps of the example I only get the placeholder value in all the buttons and I can't get them to change.
What am I doing wrong?
thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functional components are different from class components. As you can read from official documentation [react components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).
Your `Boxes` component is declared as functional component. `this.state` syntax is valid just inside class component. In that case correct way to update state would be to call `this.setState(<newstate>)` function avilable to all class components. You can read more here [react state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

You can provide state to functional components via hooks. In particolar `useState` hook. Here is explained how to do [useState hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

In your case (functional component) you can dop like this:

import hook with:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
```

then you need to initialize boxes state like this

```
const [boxes, setBoxes] = useState(context.boxes)
```

The function you will set as onClick handler is:

```
boxAct = (index) => { if (boxes[index] === null) {
     let newBoxes = boxes;
     nexBoxes[index] = '+';
     setBoxes(newBoxes);
     }
}
```

Be aware also that you should not pass data via `context api`, `context api` is used to provide global information such as application language or theme. Read more here [react context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: thank you! I'm new in react and it's very difficult for me!